# Canvas/Js is non visible

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a canvas. My console does not show any issues. However, the canvas is just not shown and I was not able to find the error, nor did I found a comparable answer in the archive. I would very much appreciate, if somebody has a hint for me. Here is js.fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hxna032/

My JS Code:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        console.log(ctx);
        ctx.strokeStyle = '28d1fa';
        ctx.lineWidth = 17;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
        ctx.shadowColor = '28d1fa';

        function degtoRad(degree) {

            var factor = Math.PI / 180;
            return degree * factor;
        }

        function donutChart() {
            var record = 1200; // equal to 100% or 360°
            var average = 120;
            var income = 127;
            var target = 170;

            //Background
            gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(250, 250, 5, 250, 250, 300);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, '09303a');
            gradient.addColorStop(1, 'black');
            ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
            ctx.fillStyle = '#1adda4';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

            // Record
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arg(250, 250, 200, degtoRad(270), degtoRad(360 - 90));
            ctx.stroke();

            // Average
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arg(250, 250, 170, degtoRad(270), degtoRad((average / record * 360) - 90));
            ctx.stroke();

            //Income
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arg(250, 250, 140, degtoRad(270), degtoRad((income / record * 360) - 90));
            ctx.stroke();

            // target
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arg(250, 250, 110, degtoRad(270), degtoRad((target / record * 360) - 90));
            ctx.stroke();


            // Income
            ctx.font = "25px Arial";
            ctx.fillStyle = '28d1fa';
            ctx.fillText(income, 175, 250);

            //Target
            ctx.font = "15px Arial";
            ctx.fillStyle = '28d1fa';
            ctx.fillText(target, 175, 280);

        }

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        document.getElementById('myImage').src = dataURL;
```

HTML:

```
  <canvas class="panel_block" id="canvas" width='500' height="500"></canvas>
    <img id="myImage" />
```

Comment: A few typos: you never call `donutChart` function, you forgot the `#` before the gradient's color-stop, it's `ctx.arc`  not `ctx.arg` https://jsfiddle.net/8hxna032/1/

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me like your canvas IS visible, you just haven't given it a different background from the web page.

Comment: @Amber Smith I don't know why you are downvoting. I told you why it "isn't visible". You're code isn't drawing because you never call your function and your colors inside it are invalid.

Comment: I am new to the forum and do not even have the possibility to vote... sorry, it wasn´t me. ;)

Comment: @CalebBlack Guesses why your answer was downvoted(which by the way requires a minimum reputation of 125, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)): While possibly right, it doesn't answer the question, it doesn't address why the code is failing(the various typos), and finally, you answered a typo question.  The goal at SO is to build a repository of knowledge useful to more than just the one who asked the question, and fixing typos is unlikely to do that.

Comment: It wasn`t just a matter of typos. I also didn´t call the function. However, there are not just experts in this world and some typos might seem intuitive for you, but it isn´t for me...

Comment: @AmberSmith The answer still doesn't address why the code didn't work in the first place.  And like I said; those were guesses.

Comment: @Daedalus It wasn't a guess, I ran the code and saw the canvas was there.

Comment: @CalebBlack I was referring to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391611/canvas-js-is-non-visible/47391852?noredirect=1#comment81758150_47391852), not your answer.  Please read it to understand.